# manipulating form field values with jQuery that has had the form loaded into the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I have a HTML form that I move up and down the DOM based on cetain actions the user takes, so the address form is loaded into a variable to be re-injected into the DOM at a later point.

```
/* Load the address form into a variable to be re-injected into the dom later */
var address_form = $('#address_temp').html();
$('#address_temp').remove();
```

Further down I make a AJAX call and based on the response I wish to populate the form fields with values. So, the form has an address1, address2, and postcode in it and i would like to do something like:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/qualify/",
   dataType: "json",
   data: {
      ajax : 'true',
      lookup : 'true',
      postcode : $('#avail_input').val()                
   },
   success: function(data) {    
      $('#address1').val(data.street);          
      $('#address2').val(data.city);
      $('#postcode').val(data.postcode);
}});
```

However, this does not work as the address has already been loaded into the DOM and a copy has been placed in a variable. How can I replace the value of the form fields? Do I need to re-load it back into the DOM to manipulate it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of saving the form as a html string copy the dom itself as a jquery object:

```
/* Load the address form into a variable to be re-injected into the dom later */
var address_form = $('#address_temp').clone(true);
$('#address_temp').remove();
```

Then you can manipulate the dom of your form even if it's not in your document's dom:

```
success: function(data) {    
      $('#address1', address_form).val(data.street);          
      $('#address2', address_form).val(data.city);
      $('#postcode', address_form).val(data.postcode);
}
```

What I'm doing is searching for the following id's inside of `address_form`.

P.S.

A more clean equivalent in my opinion would be changing, but it's mostly a matter of taste :)

```
success: function(data) {
    address_form
        .find('#address1').val(data.street).end()
        .find('#address2').val(data.city).end()
        .find('#postcode').val(data.postcode);
}
```

You might wanna read about jQuery's [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method.

Comment: Does the second block of code you have provided actually change the value of the form field? After adding in the code you provided, i'm doing `var address_form_str = address_form.html(); $('#options_container').html(address_form_str);` But `address_form_str` does not include the updated values.

Comment: First of all, why do you need to turn it into html? Use this: `$('#options_container').empty().append(address_form);` and it should work just fine. I just wanna make sure, the success method has access to `address_form`? Do you have any errors in your console log? Are you sure `data` contains the values it should?

Comment: No, there's no error in the console log. I am using the latest version of Firefox. The success method definitely has access to the address_form as I can dump it out with a console.log. The empty/append approach doesn't work either. I have tried changing the `data` values to being something arbitrary, but it doesn't update the form.

Comment: If I manipulate the form as you have suggested then convert it to HTML with `.html()` then I should get the form with the edited values - am I right?

Comment: Yeah, you should, there's just no reason to do it. Let me make a code example for you, it might clarify things.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. I'd really need to try and fix this sooner rather than later too.

Comment: It's just for the example of it. Ignore the missing parts :) http://jsfiddle.net/L6wzE/

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for your help! Great answer and fantastic effort.

Answer (score 0):

In the success handler you will have to manipulate the `address_form` variable. I believe this can be done like so:

```
  success: function(data) {    
        address_form.find('#address1').val(data.street);          
        address_form.find('#address2').val(data.city);
        address_form.find('#postcode').val(data.postcode);
  }
```

Comment: That throws and error (`TypeError: address_form.find is not a function`) in Firebug on the first usage of `find`.

Comment: In your answer `address_form` is a string, not a jquery object.